# Rails 3 + Mongoid: A good way to let users sort records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, mongoid

I need a good (which means easy and comprehensible) way to let users sort records in an app that uses Rails 3 and Mongoid.

To clarify what I mean: let's say there is a `Recipe` that has a number of `Ingredients`. At the moment, those recipes have no feature to let the user (who can edit the `Recipe`) sort the ingredients in a way he/she wants.

Until now I mostly did sorting stuff with a numeric sort order field where the user has to increase/decrease the number of a record to sort it up or down - there has to be a better way (gem?) to do this I guess, but I haven't found much.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Recipe` example is close to what you're doing then you should use embedded documents for your `Ingredient`s. If you have something like this:

```
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :ingredients
  # Recipe name, ... fields.
end
class Ingredient
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :recipe
  # Ingredient name, amount, ... fields.
end
```

then the ingredients would actually be an array of hashes inside the recipe and recipes would look like this inside MongoDB:

```
{
  ingredients: [
    { ingredient... },
    ...
  ],
  name: '...',
  ...
}
```

Since the ingredients are an array, they are implicitly ordered and reordering them is a simple matter of moving things around in the array.

If the "ingredients" need to be separate top-level entities on their own then the embedded ingredients would reference the top-level ingredient in the usual way. If the "ingredients" are really just a list of `id`s then use an `Array` field to store them and use the order of the array elements to define the ingredient order.

You might notice that all the above are just different ways to use `Array` fields to handle the ordering.

Comment: thank you, I already used arrays for doing sorting in the past, too. was just thinking there might be a better way to accomplish this.